# Client-side Prediction Divergence with Input Packets and Time Differences | Multiplayer FPS

Tags: networking, multiplayer, client-server, first-person-shooter, udp

I am running into a problem while implementing client-side prediction in my multiplayer FPS. I'm not entirely sure if I've completely and correctly understood the concepts. I have read the articles from Gambetta and from Valve, as well as several others.

What I'm currently doing is sending client input as key presses and key releases; the client sends when it presses 'W', for instance, and sends a packet once it has stopped pressing 'W'. The client then predicts the movement in a fully-deterministic way. The server then sends a position packets to all of the clients and the client checks if there is any divergence and corrects for it.

I am now running into the issue if the time between the input packets on departure differs from the time of the input packets on arrival, it will inevitably lead to small errors and massive divergence over time as the server will think the client will have pressed a key for longer or less time than it actually has. I haven't seen anyone mention this, so I'm questioning if what I'm doing is right.

Another issue I am seeing with this approach is that the client sends rotation updates to the server at 64hz (my tick-rate). This will, of course, lead to small differences in rotation from the server and client at specific times. Given that the movement is dependent on the orientation/rotation of the player, client-side prediction errors will inevitably ensue.

One way I was thinking that could fix the first problem, would be to send timestamps along with the input packets and have the server rewind positions and compensate for the delay imprecisions. Before I follow through with that, I am seeking some confirmation as to what I'm doing is right.

Any help would be appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: I recommend never asking here "is what I am doing right?" — you'll get much better answers by coding it and testing for yourself "does what I am doing *work*?" If your game works, nobody will care what hearsay from Internet strangers says is "right". ;) It sounds like you've got an idea for using time stamps to ensure everyone's agreed on the timing/ordering of the events. That's a solution that can be implemented in a way that works, or it can be implemented in ways that do not work. Implement it. If it doesn't work, show us your implementation and we'll help you fix it.

Comment: I'm also having this issue and I was thinking about doing th same thing, but it looks pretty dicey to implement. Did you solve this? If so, what did you do?